# For some reason, the value of the list, chars, is reset whenever a condition is checked within an if statement, breaking the program

Tags: python, string, list, algorithm

I am trying to make a function that takes in a string and runs the following encryption algorithm: every character at an odd position i in the alphabet will be encrypted with the character at position i + 1, and every character at an even position i will be encrypted with the character at position i - 1. In other words, ‘a’ is encrypted with ‘b’, ‘b’ with ‘a’, ‘c’ with ‘d’, ‘d’ with ‘c’, and so on. Lowercase characters should remain lowercase, and uppercase characters should remain uppercase. In other words, 'bob' would output as 'apa'.

Although I eventually figured out the issue, I still don't know why using chars[i] instead of stg[i] within my conditionals broke the program. From my observations it seems that the list was getting reset at random intervals. Can anyone explain why swapping the variables fixed my program? Thank you!

Broken Program:

```
def easyCryto(stg=''):

    # Alphabet list
    alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    cap_alpha = [i.upper() for i in alpha]
    
    # Converts the string into a list
    chars = []
    for char in stg:
        chars.append(char)

    # Encyription Algorithm
    for i in range(len(chars)):
        for j in range(len(alpha)):
            
            # Checks if letter are odd
            if (j + 1) % 2 == 1:
                if chars[i] == alpha[j]:
                    try: # Block 1
                        if chars[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[j + 1]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[j + 1]
                    except:
                        if chars[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[0]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[0]

                elif chars[i] == cap_alpha[j]:
                    chars[i] = cap_alpha[j + 1]

            # Checks if letter are even
            elif (j + 1) % 2 == 0:
                if chars[i] == alpha[j]:
                    try: # Block 1
                        if chars[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[j - 1]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[j - 1]

                    except:
                        if chars[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[-1]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[-1]

                elif chars[i] == cap_alpha[j]:
                    chars[i] = cap_alpha[j - 1]

    return ''.join(chars)

print(easyCryto('Willy'))
```

Fixed Program:

```
def easyCryto(stg=''):

    # Alphabet list
    alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    cap_alpha = [i.upper() for i in alpha]
    
    # Converts the string into a list
    chars = []
    for char in stg:
        chars.append(char)

    # Encyription Algorithm
    for i in range(len(chars)):
        for j in range(len(alpha)):

            # Checks if letter are odd
            if (j + 1) % 2 == 1:
                if stg[i] == alpha[j]:
                    try: # Block 1
                        if stg[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[j + 1]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[j + 1]
                    except:
                        if stg[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[0]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[0]

                elif stg[i] == cap_alpha[j]:
                    chars[i] = cap_alpha[j + 1]

            # Checks if letter are even
            elif (j + 1) % 2 == 0:
                if stg[i] == alpha[j]:
                    try: # Block 1
                        if stg[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[j - 1]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[j - 1]

                    except:
                        if stg[i] not in cap_alpha:
                            chars[i] = alpha[-1]
                        else:
                            chars[i] = cap_alpha[-1]

                elif stg[i] == cap_alpha[j]:
                    chars[i] = cap_alpha[j - 1]

    return ''.join(chars)

print(easyCryto('bob'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never *break* out of the loop after a replacement, so the replacement loop keeps going. This is not an issue when replacing "backwards" e.g. replacing b by a, because you're iterating `alpha` forwards so it won't match again. However when you replace `a` by `b`, on the next iteration of the loop it's immediately going to find a new replacement match and swap `b` (originally `a`) back to `a`.

That's easy to see by just printing the state of the replacement loop:

```
c=b a=a
c=b a=b
c=a a=c
c=a a=d
c=a a=e
c=a a=f
c=a a=g
c=a a=h
c=a a=i
c=a a=j
c=a a=k
c=a a=l
c=a a=m
c=a a=n
c=a a=o
c=a a=p
c=a a=q
c=a a=r
c=a a=s
c=a a=t
c=a a=u
c=a a=v
c=a a=w
c=a a=x
c=a a=y
c=a a=z
c=o a=a
c=o a=b
c=o a=c
c=o a=d
c=o a=e
c=o a=f
c=o a=g
c=o a=h
c=o a=i
c=o a=j
c=o a=k
c=o a=l
c=o a=m
c=o a=n
c=o a=o
c=p a=p
c=o a=q
c=o a=r
c=o a=s
c=o a=t
c=o a=u
c=o a=v
c=o a=w
c=o a=x
c=o a=y
c=o a=z
c=b a=a
c=b a=b
c=a a=c
c=a a=d
c=a a=e
c=a a=f
c=a a=g
c=a a=h
c=a a=i
c=a a=j
c=a a=k
c=a a=l
c=a a=m
c=a a=n
c=a a=o
c=a a=p
c=a a=q
c=a a=r
c=a a=s
c=a a=t
c=a a=u
c=a a=v
c=a a=w
c=a a=x
c=a a=y
c=a a=z
```

`c = chars[i]`, `a = alpha[j]`. On `c=b` you can see that the replacement is quickly done then we keep going for no reason, but on `c=o`, you can see that it reaches `a=o`, flips to `c=p` but at that point `a=p` so we flip back to `c=o`.

By using `stg` to check this is not a factor because the original data is not flipped. An alternative is to `break` after you've found the `alpha[j]` matching a `chars[i]`.

The script seems overly complicated though:

- you're checking against `cap_alpha` *within* having checked against `alpha`, since the sets are non-overlapping I don't see how that could ever do something useful.
- the try/except don't seem useful? I could have seen a modulo issue, but in your scheme `z` is swapped for `y` so nothing interesting happens

More importantly you're not making use of Python's facilities e.g. `string` already provides alphabets, `str.translate` can take a conversion table, `list.index` will return the index of an item within the list (it raises an exception when it doesn't find anything though, `str.find` is convenient because it just returns `None` then), `chr` and `ord` will convert from and to codepoint number, you can use bit manipulation to flip numbers around, ...

You could probably do this using bit twiddling (and it might even be fun), but as a first approximation I'd just build a translation table and use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). It's not the simplest thing to grasp but quite convenient once you grok it:

```py
# str.maketrans can take various formats to build the translation
# table. Here we're going to use the simplest, a dictionary mapping
# unicode ordinals (letter codes) to other unicode ordinals, the
# mapping is the transformation we want to define
tr = {}
# iterate on the codes of "odd" letters (a, c, e, g, ...) and create
# the entries to map both forward (a -> b) and backwards (b -> a)
for letter in range(ord('a'), ord('z'), 2):
    tr[letter] = letter+1
    tr[letter+1] = letter
# repeat for uppercase
for letter in range(ord('A'), ord('Z'), 2):
    tr[letter] = letter+1
    tr[letter+1] = letter
table = str.maketrans(tr)

def easyCryto(stg=''):
    return stg.translate(table)

print(easyCryto('Willy'))
```

Comment: With bit twiddling (which is just XOR with 1) and slight golfing, the complete function can just be `return ''.join([chr(((ord(c)-1)^1)+1)for c in stg])`

Comment: you don't even need the square brackets fwiw, `str.join` is happy to take an arbitrary iterator so a gencomp works fine.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It was a remnant when I was doing it in print statement with `*[...]` (which doesn't take generator).